# How to filter three way many-to-many relationship in graphql and sequelize?

Tags: typescript, express, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo

I've setup a GraphQL Apollo server with express and sequelize-typescript for the backend. I have a **three way many-to-many relationship** between the following tables/models:

```
Action{
    id: Int
    name: String
    participants:[Participant]
    participanttypes: [ParticipantType]
}
Participant{
    id: Int
    displayname: String
    actions: [Action]
    participanttypes: [ParticipantType]
}
ParticipantType{
   id: Int
   description: String
   actions: [Action]
   participants: [Participant]
}
```

All three are joined together using a fourth model

```
ActionParticipants{
   id: Int
   action: Int
   participant: Int
   participanttype: Int
}
```

I'm having trouble filtering the above datastructures using GraphQL.
For instance, I want to get an Action, then Participants on that Action, then the ParticipantType description of each participant on the Action. E.g. with a getAction(id:1) query that returns the first Action

```
getAction(id:1){
  name
  participants{
    displayName
    participanttypes{
      description
    }
  }
}
```

With the above query I will receive the name of the action, then an array of participants[name] on that action, and lastly all the participanttype descriptions for each participant.

However, I want to filter the participanttype to only the Participant(s) on that Action.